# Spyder always pops up cmd window when starting up

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Every time I start Spyder from Anaconda the cmd window pops out.If I close the window,Spyder closes too.It just looks very annoying.[Here is the window that pops out:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaTfH.png)